# How to determine if the user is known or not using pam_authenticate?

Tags: c++, linux, pam

I am authenticating a user and I want to determine if the user is known (a valid existing username) or unknown.

```
int ret = pam_authenticate(pamh, PAM_DISALLOW_NULL_AUTHTOK);
```

Now even if the username is unknown, `pam_authenticate` returns `PAM_AUTH_ERR` instead of (expected) `PAM_USER_UNKNOWN`.

How to find if the username is known or not?

Comment: The objective is questionable. It is generally considered poor practice to distinguish between 'unknown user' and 'incorrect password', as it leaks information to the attacker.

Comment: @EJP: The distinction is required only for internal logging.

Comment: Attackers can be internal as well as external.

Comment: Yes, but if you can't assume that you can safely keep all relevant information in system logs, you have bigger problems than just "bad username" vs. "bad password".

Answer (score 3):

Since the program will run internal, you can detect if a user name exists by reading `/etc/passwd` . The first entry of the file is the user name. PAM itself doesn't tell if the user name exists for reasons EJP pointed out.

Comment: As user database might not be stored there, you might want to use "getent passwd username" command or its equivalent instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ruben's answer is correct but instead of reading directly from `/etc/passwd` OR `/etc/shadow`, I used linux functions [getpwnam](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam) and [getspnam](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getspnam) which do the same work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The result here depends on the results of the backends used by your system.
These backends and their order are set in /etc/nsswitch.conf

They are in the form :

```
passwd: files MODNAME
group:  files MODNAME
hosts:  files dns
```

Where "MODNAME" correspond to a file located in :
`/lib64/security/pam_MODNAME.so` (or /lib/security for 32bits systems).

Modname can be something like `compat` or `ldap` or any network related database.

The result you'll get in pam_authenticate depends on the configuration of your `/etc/pam.d/`  and your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` configuration.

If you have anything other than "file" in the "passwd" section, try removing the secondary backend (but beware to keep a way to restore it).

If with only the "files" database (witch corresponds to /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow) you are still not getting the "PAM_USER_UNKNOWN", it is definitely PAM related. Otherwise, it's backend related.